# trouble working with map iterators in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I am trying to go through my map of patient IDs, find the sequential ones that match, and find the difference squared for each pair of results (for the same patient). However I am having some trouble with the "itid" iterator in the line, "for (itid = nx; itid != mymap.end(); itid++) {" and I'm not sure why. When I take out the code with "itid" it works just fine. I am a programming beginner, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
map <int,struct testInfo> mymap;
map <int,struct testInfo>:: iterator it;
pair<map<int,struct testInfo>::iterator,bool> ret;
map <int,struct testInfo>:: iterator itid;



    int arraySize = 10000;
    double diffsq[arraySize];
    int count = 1;

    for ( it=mymap.begin() ; it != mymap.end(); it++ ) {

        auto nx = next(it);

        //comparing each patientID to the next patientID
        if ((it->second.patientID == nx->second.patientID) && it->second.patientID != 0) {

            for (itid = nx; itid != mymap.end(); itid++) {

                if ((it->second.patientID == itid->second.patientID) && it->second.patientID != 0) {

                    diffsq[count] = pow((it->second.result - itid->second.result), 2); 
                    count++;

                } else
                    itid = mymap.end();

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: After the initialization of `nx`, `nx` may be the end iterator, but you don't check for that.

Comment: what does the int represent in map<int, struct TestInfo> ?

Comment: I suspect that "some trouble" is caused by `itid = mymap.end();` (it's a bad combination with the follwing `itid++`). Why does that line exist?

Comment: Hi molbdnilo, thanks so much! I think what I intended was to get out of the "for" loop... but obviously I didn't think it through. I changed it to else break;

Comment: Specify "some trouble".

Comment: Hi Kerrek SB, you're right, thanks for the tip! I added ` if(next(it) == mymap.end()) break;` and now the code runs. It's still not giving me any results though, still need to work on other bugs...

Comment: @WernerHenze well the trouble now is that for some reason my code doesn't run if arraySize is greater than 100000, and I need it in the 100 million range...

Comment: Please specify "my code doesn't run". Maybe your Array on the stack is too large and you program gets killed because it exceeds the allowed stacksize?

Comment: @WernerHenze I think you might be right. How can I find out the allowed stacksize? I'm also considering using a vector instead. Sorry about not being specific - I'm not too sure how to interpret the error message Xcode is giving me. It just says lldb and points to the " if(next(it) == mymap.end()) break;" line.

Comment: @aspn And we can't help you if you don't give the error Messages you get. Provide all **necessary** Information or you won't get help. [mcve]

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks for the link! i'll try to ask a more verifiable question next time. turns out changing the array into a vector works.

Comment: @aspn vector allocates from the heap, the Array from the stack. That might be the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the `next` give a constant iterator and itid is not `constant`... try it in same way as you have done `auto nx` try same for itid.
`auto itid = nx` inside the for loop.

Comment: Hi Ajay, I actually tried auto itid = nx first and it gave me an error, which is why I changed it

Comment: @aspn Is the present problem is run time ? and what error you got on having `auto itid = nx ` ?

Comment: Ajay @Bob__ turns out the problem was not checking for "nx" as the end iterator. I changed it back to "auto itid = nx" but from what I see both ways are able to run now with the "nx" part corrected